# Need a vba macro to search through a field of cells to look for a match and return the row number that it finds the match in

Tags: excel, vba

I apologize as I am a complete novice, but I am trying to write a macro for excel that will go through a column of names on one sheet and then search through a field of cells on a second sheet and return the row number that it finds a match. Sorry if that sounds confusing, here's a picture to help clarify

[image]

I'm looking for a macro that will return in sheet 1 column B the matching rows, ie 9 then 3 then 10.

I realize I'm asking a lot, but as an excel fledgling, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following *UDF*

```
Public Function Findname(s As String, rLook As Range) As Long
    Findname = 0
    For Each r In rLook
        If r.Text = s Then
            Findname = r.Row
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=findname(A1,Sheet2!A1:G18)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**